# Как создать и раскатать по сети настроенный образ Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, администрирование, pxe, сетевое-администрирование

Нужно создать образ windows, настроить, установить софт, затем раскатать его по сети на полсотни машин.
Думал создать что-то вроде настроенной сборки и раскатать по PXE, но не разобрался, как нормально это сделать.
В распоряжении ubuntu server. В приоритете, лучше как-то задействовать его, чтоб в случае проблем мог просто заново по сети поставить образ. На крайний случай существует возможность поднять что-то вроде tinyPXE на одном из windows компов и с него всё раскатать.
Сталкивались ли вы с таким заданием и как решили? Лучше максимально подробное описание, или со ссылками на инструкции.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ну я сталкивался в ноябре 2010. Щас продолжаю сталкиваться. ~5к установок за спиной и конца и края не видно, потому что мир меняется - нужно подстраиваться. Начни с `tftpd`, `grub` (syslinux к сожалению походу всё), `clonezilla live`, `gparted live`, `nginx`. Образ собирай внутри Virtualbox. Больше расписывать смысла не вижу, потому что документации под это всё - не один десяток статей. Слишком общий вопрос ты задал. Акронис и прочую проприетарщину не бери, нагребёшься, поверь.

Comment: @donRumata, а разве нельзя тем же clonezilla-live скопировать образ диска с уже настроенного компа, кинуть на сервер и раскатать по остальным? Звучит куда проще. Плюс объём диска на всех пк одинаковый, максимум 100мб не размечать пространства на исходном компе, чтоб оставить запас на расхождение в объёме дисков.

Comment: Ну если железо одинаковое, то можно. А вот когда ты будешь ловить синьку из-за неподходящего драйвера `usb 3.0` или ещё чего по-хуже - то перечитаешь мой камент и поймёшь, что самое очевидное решение - не значит самое правильное.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое удобное, что я нашёл: использую `clonezilla live`. Сначала с настроенного компа копирую образ на samba-сервер, потом раскатываю его по компам. В случае чего, можно будет опять раскатать, ведь образ на сервере останется. Если нужно раскатать только раз, то есть опция, чтоб с одной машины сразу перекидывать на несколько других.